# Estoy aprendiendo Javascript, estoy en la parte de clases, al parecer el código está bien escrito pero no una parte no me corre

Tags: javascript

Mento un problema con este código, no me muestra en consola como supongo debería ser.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si no agregas tu código como texto así como la salida que obtienes, la salida esperada y el error obtenido poco podemos hacer amigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema principal es que se te olvido usar los parentesis `()` para invocar al metodo, si tu **NO** usas los parentesis para invocar al metodo, la consola asumira que lo que quieres **NO** es ejecutar tu metodo, si no mas bien imprimir el metodo entero.

Otro problema que tienes es que estas intentando usar comillas dobles (`""`) en vez de backticks (``), para renderizar en tu caso las propiedades de tu clase, aquello que **intentas se conoce como interpolacion, y esto solo lo permiten los backticks** (``), por lo tanto debes de reemplazar esto:

```
console.log("La pantalla ${this.marca} de modelo ${this.modelo} es de ${this.pulgadas} ");
```

por:

```
console.log(`La pantalla ${this.marca} de modelo ${this.modelo} es de ${this.pulgadas} `);
```

Para solucionar el segundo error y principal, es que en vez de escribir en la consola:

```
tvHabitacion.info;
```

deberias haber escrito:

```
tvHabitacion.info();
```

Recuerda que `info`, **NO** es una propiedad de tu clase, si no un `metodo` por lo tanto debes invocarlo usando parentesis al final `()`.

Comment: Tienes razon,  es que pense que en la imagen habia visto que usaba backticks,  gracias,  voy a corregirlo.

Answer (score 1):

Para usar la interpolación de cadenas debes abrir y cerrar con el carácter backticks **( ` )** con eso ya deberia funcionarte.

```
console.log(`La pantalla ${this.marca} de modelo ${this.modelo} es de ${this.pulgadas}`);
```

tambien puedes concatenar las cadenas con los atributos, por ejemplo:

```
console.log("La pantalla " + this.marca + " de modelo " + this.modelo + "es de " + this.pulgadas);
```

Te dejo este [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) con información de apoyo.

Comment: Se llaman backticks y sería más recomendable este enlace https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings

Comment: Y no se suman las cadenas amigo en todo caso lo que estás haciendo es concatenar

Comment: Gracias @BetaM, tienes razón, utilice mal el concepto, ya que es concatenar como indicas, y con respecto al nombre, creo que es mejor colocar el carácter, no puedo saber si lo conocerá por su nombre, voy a tomar a modificar la respuesta, para que quede mas apropiada y tomare tu link, muchas gracias por el aporte.